# free displays incorrect memory on Nexus 10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ram, nexus-10

I'm playing about with Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus 10 ([which should have 2GB RAM](https://www.google.co.uk/nexus/10/specs/)).

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1.1G       1.0G        90M       7.1M        34M       716M
-/+ buffers/cache:       259M       841M
Swap:         511M        12K       511M
```

Any ideas why total memory is shown as 1.1GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an 1100/900 ratio between the system and video memory.

Since 900M is reserved for video at boot, the system can only see the remaining 1.1G.

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus10/comments/1jt6o7/new_nexus_10_only_appears_to_have_1gb_of_ram_wtf/)